# Return List from JSON Url c#

Tags: c#, json, arraylist

I need a List from JSON URL, but I don't know how I do this information from this above List

```
   ///www.omdbapi.com/
    const string ApiKey = "18693fd6";

    /// <summary>
    /// By Search
    /// www.omdbapi.com/?s=titulo&apikey=18693fd6
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="filtro"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public List<Film> ListarFilmes(string filtro)
    {

        List<Film> ResultFilm = new List<Film>();

        using (WebClient webClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
        {
            var json = webClient.DownloadString("http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=" + filtro + "&apikey=" + ApiKey);
            dynamic array = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
            ResultFilm.Add(array) ;
        }

        return ResultFilm;
    }
```

This is a class of Filme that I need return in the List with Title and Year varibles

```
    public class Film
    {
    /// <summary>
    /// Title
    /// </summary>
    public string Title { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Year
    /// </summary>
    public int? Year { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That json is returning more than an array of films. The structure looks like this:

```
{
  "Search": [
    {
      "Title": "Sin t\u00c3\u00adtulo (Carta para Serra)",
      "Year": "2011",
      "imdbID": "tt2268553",
      "Type": "movie",
      "Poster": "N\/A"
    },
    {
      "Title": "Pendiente de T\u00c3\u00adtulo",
      "Year": "2008",
      "imdbID": "tt2301959",
      "Type": "series",
      "Poster": "N\/A"
    },
    .....more items here...... 
  ],
  "totalResults": "17",
  "Response": "True"
}
```

You need to access property `Search` to get the list of films. This code will get you a list of Film objects including title and year.

```
JToken search = JObject.Parse(json).GetValue("Search");
ResultFilm = search.Select(f => f.ToObject<Film>()).ToList();
```

Note that Json contains 10 films, not 17 as stated in `totalResults`.

Comment: Isn't filling the fields Title and Year for the object Film

Comment: This worked fine. Even before my last edit, it was retrieving data. You need to access property "Search", otherwise it raises an exception. Cannot simply parse the whole thing as List<Film>.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried ? I'm assuming the object returned is just the list of films

```
ResultFilm = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Film>>(json);
```